# Unity 2017.2 version with ARkit is not building with Xcode 9.1

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine, arkit

I have downloaded latest version of Unity 3D for Mac ( 2017.2)and imported the latest version of the ARKIT from the below location https://bitbucket.org/Unity-Technologies/unity-arkit-plugin. It is able to successfully build the unity package for iOS however in Xcode when we tried to build and run it gives lot of error msgs like Use of undeclared identifier "ARSession configuration". Similarly lot of compatibility errors are coming. Can some one let me know if Unity be used with latest version of Xcode.

Attached the screenshot for your reference. [image]